# <li> be moved to another <ul> by vue

Tags: vue.js, html-lists

I'm building a list that users can choose items.
It would be a nested list with at least 3 layers.

As  can only offer one layer of sub-option, I would like to build it as `<ul>` and `<li>`.

But I can't figure out how to change my code with two `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Hope someone could give me some ideas.

Here are what I have

```
<div id="applyApp" class="container">
    <div class="pool">
      <ul>
        <h3 @click.prevent="isShow = !isShow">Category</h3>
        <li v-for="items in filterData" :value="items.id">
{{items.id}} {{items.ame}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="selected-item">
        <li v-for="items in secondLayer" :value="items.id">
{{items.id}} {{items.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
  el: "#applyApp",
  data: {
    firstLayer: [
      {
        name: "name1",
        id: "0101",
      },
      {
        name: "name2",
        id: "010101",
      },
      {
        name: "name3",
        id: "010101001B",
      },
    ],
    secondLayer: [],
    firstLayerValue: [],
    secondLayerValue: [],
  },
  methods: {
    moveHelper(value, arrFrom, arrTo) {
      const index = arrFrom.findIndex(function (el) {
        return el.id == value;
      });
      const item = arrFrom[index];

      arrFrom.splice(index, 1);
      arrTo.push(item);
    },
    addItems() {
      const selected = this.firstLayerValue.slice(0);
      for (const i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) {
        this.moveHelper(selected[i], this.firstLayer, this.secondLayer);
      }
    },
    removeItems() {
      const selected = this.secondLayerValue.slice(0);

      for (const i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) {
        this.moveHelper(selected[i], this.secondLayer, this.firstLayer);
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @StarkButtowski sorry for being indistinct. I have two problem, 1) how to create a nested list (which have solved by procoib). 2) I have two <ul> (haven't been selected / selected), when I clicked a <li> in <ul> (haven't been selected), the <li> will move to <ul> (selected).

Answer (score 0):

If you want nested items in your list, you might have to use a recursion component, which means adding child data to your items. And calling the component inside of itself until it exhausts the list of children, by taking the data props of the child in every call.

```js
Vue.component("listRecursion", {
  props: ['listData'],
  name: "listRecursion",
  template: `
  <div>
    <ul v-for="item in listData">
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      <list-recursion v-if="item.children.length" :list-data="item.children"/>
    </ul>
  </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        name: "name1",
        id: "0101",
        children: [
          {
            name: "sub item 1",
            id: "0d201",
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "sub item 2",
            id: "020g1",
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "sub item 3",
            id: "20201",
            children: [
               {
                name: "subsub item 1",
                id: "40201",
                children: [
                  {
                  name: "subsub item 1",
                  id: "40201",
                  children: [
                    {
                    name: "subsubsub item 1",
                    id: "40201",
                    children: []
                  }]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: "subsub item 2",
                id: "50201",
                children: []
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "name2",
        id: "010101",
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: "name3",
        id: "010101001B",
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Recursive list:</h2>
  <list-recursion :list-data="todos"/>
</div>
```

As you can see, this saves you from manually adding new levels, just add to the data to the child nodes

Comment: Thank you @procoib ! It's a good solution for a nest list.

Comment: Reading your reply to StarkButtowski , are you looking for a collapsible list? its not very clear what you are looking for to be honest

Comment: Yes, I would like to hava a collapsible list, and wish I can switch <li> between two <ul>. I found I can do it easily with <select>, <option> tag by using v-model, but I don't know how to do it with <ul>, <li> tag

Comment: "and wish I can switch <li> between two <ul>" this is the part that confuses me, can you give me an example/use case?

Comment: here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/shanyulin/pen/XWXErJb  
When I click "red", "orange"..., they will jump to another <select> area.

Comment: Your codepen example isnt working, but i can see more of the design. So from left to right, you display each sub item as you click, and you wish the items to be draggable to other sections?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Okay il see how i would approach this

Comment: Sorry for bother you again! I tried the above list recursion, it seems that the number of list is limited. Do you know what'w wrong with that?

Comment: Sorry i was meant to come back to this code yesterday. What does your data look like? Note that the component is looping through the children key

Comment: Oh, please don't be sorry about that :) This is what I get now: https://codepen.io/shanyulin/pen/jOWZgbZ?editors=1010

The data has 4 levels, but the when I add more then 4 objects, it can't render on the screen.

Comment: Okay so be sure that every item has a "children" key, even if the array is empty: https://codepen.io/mcwalshh/pen/oNbqWwe?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand this recursion method.

Answer (score 0):

I see @procoib which solves your first case and for the li rearrange, you can do the same approach similar to 'select' which is shown below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      first: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      second: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    alter: function (index, src, desc) {
      this[desc].push(this[src].splice(index, 1)[0])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>First</h1>
  <ul id="firstList">
    <li v-for="(_, i) in first" v-on:click="alter(i, 'first', 'second')">{{_}}</li>
  </ul>
  
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <ul id="secondList">
    <li v-for="(_, i) in second" v-on:click="alter(i, 'second', 'first')">{{_}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> If you click any number for a list, it is added to the other list.